# Python 2.7 super method can't see child class name

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, super

Got the code like below:

```
class Type:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

class MyCls(Type):
    def __init__(self, index):
        super(MyCls, self).__init__(index)
```

And after trying to compile - got next error message on the `super` line:

> Detail NameError: global name 'MyCls' is not defined

How should I define `MyCls` to make the above code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet you've shown shouldn't trigger a NameError - classes are allowed to refer to themselves in this way

However, `super` only works with new-style classes - trying to instantiate a `MyCls` object will raise a TypeError. To fix this, the class `Type` needs to explicitly inherit from `object`:

```
class Type(object):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
```

`MyCls` can stay as it is in this case. Then you have:

```
>>> a = MyCls(6)
>>> a
<__main__.MyCls object at 0x7f5ca8c2aa10>
>>> a.index
6
```

Comment: When I did as you said - I got another error: Detail TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) .  It's on the Type declaration line.

Comment: It sounds like you're passing in too many arguments - define `Type` and `MyCls` as above and then try `a = MyCls(6)`. The name `a` should point to a `MyCls` object with `a.index` equal to 6.